# Rest Assured/Stack Exchange API: Unable to get success response while trying to hit service from Eclipse

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I have tried to hit one of the stack exchange APIs using GET HTTP request for testing purpose using RESTAssured JAVA. However, I was getting 400 response code instead of 200. I tried the same using POSTMAN and it is working fine. Kindly help.

```
RestAssured.baseURI="https://api.stackexchange.com";

    RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
    ///2.2/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow
Response res = given().
    param("order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow").
    when().
get("/2.2/badges"). 
then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON). 
extract().response();
String text = res.asString();
System.out.println(text);


}
```

Response :

```
{"error_id":400,"error_message":"site is required","error_name":"bad_parameter"}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is how method param() works:

```
given().
param("order", "desc").
param("sort", "rank").
param("site", "stackoverflow").
when().
get("/2.2/badges")
```

Comment: aah! Thanks suit :) i just missed basic rule of coding.. thanks again!!